# Pod is always pending in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kind

The Pod status is always pending. I'm using Kind locally to study Kubernetes and trying to go up one Pod.

```sh
❯ kubectl get pods             
NAME       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
goserver   0/1     Pending   0          12m
```

The events from describe is none.

```sh
❯ kubectl describe pod goserver
Name:         goserver
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         <none>
Labels:       app=goserver
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Pending
IP:           
IPs:          <none>
Containers:
  goserver:
    Image:        allansduarte/hellogo
    Port:         <none>
    Host Port:    <none>
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-rjkmz (ro)
Volumes:
  kube-api-access-rjkmz:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:                      <none>
```

No logs.

```sh
❯ kubectl logs goserver
```

Kubernetes system logs.

```sh
❯ kubectl get pod -n kube-system
NAME                                              READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
coredns-558bd4d5db-62bbj                          1/1     Running   5          10d
coredns-558bd4d5db-zk9rw                          1/1     Running   5          10d
etcd-fullcycle-control-plane                      1/1     Running   0          95m
kindnet-66c9q                                     1/1     Running   5          10d
kindnet-6wfzg                                     1/1     Running   5          10d
kindnet-sklzj                                     1/1     Running   5          10d
kindnet-xjh4p                                     1/1     Running   5          10d
kube-apiserver-fullcycle-control-plane            1/1     Running   0          95m
kube-controller-manager-fullcycle-control-plane   1/1     Running   8          10d
kube-proxy-cdzrj                                  1/1     Running   5          10d
kube-proxy-jphsn                                  1/1     Running   5          10d
kube-proxy-mhdtt                                  1/1     Running   5          10d
kube-proxy-x8jbm                                  1/1     Running   5          10d
kube-scheduler-fullcycle-control-plane            1/1     Running   8          10d
```

Any suggestions to continue the investigation?

Comment: Please add output of `kubectl get pod -n kube-system` in your question

Comment: @P.... I just edited.

Comment: Output does not show any issue, did you made any changes api server ? Do you see any.logs in /var/log of the worker node ? Also Try `journalctl` to see logs.

Comment: @AllanDuarte can you please check the logs of kube-scheduler as that pod is responsible for scheduling any pod on k8s ? Also try the following command to see the events in general kubectl describe events. This command would give you an idea of what is happening when a new pod request is submitted.

Comment: Please check `kubectl logs -n kube-system kube-scheduler-fullcycle-control-plane`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to Mac OS Big Sur recently and Kubernetes and Docker did not start. Then, I just reinstall the Docker and Kubernetes. The options for reset Kubernetes, clean/purge data or reset to factory defaults don't work.